# Add input field in Magento Admin Panel

Tags: magento, admin

How can I add an `<input type ="text"/>` field in below screen shot of Magento Admin Panel to receive a value??

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you want to add "Title field".

You have to add following code on  this file i.e. `Am/Blog/Block/Adminhtml/Blog/Edit/Tab/Form.php`

```
  $fieldset->addField('title', 'text', array(
      'label'     => Mage::helper('blog')->__('Title'),
      'class'     => 'required-entry',
      'required'  => true,
      'name'      => 'title',
  ));
```